# Find rotation period of a four-body gravitational system on a square.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, physics

Four point bodies, each of mass $m$, attract each other due to the interaction
gravitational. Such bodies are at the vertices of a $L$-side square rotating around their
center with constant angular velocity. $G$ being the universal gravitational constant, the period of this
rotation is given by:

What I tried:

$ F_R = F '+ F_ {DB} $

vector

so, $ F_{DB}= \frac{GM^2}{(L\sqrt{2})^2}$

answer:
$2\pi \sqrt{\frac{L^3}{GM}(\frac{4-\sqrt{2}}{7})}$

Comment: Please define your variables.  It looks like $F_{DB}$ is the force from the diagonally opposite mass, but you have ignored the forces from the other two.  You then leave out all the steps to the period.  What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The net attraction force on each mass is the sum of the gravitational attractions from the other three masses and points to the center of the square,

$$F=\frac{Gm^2}{(\sqrt2 L)^2}+2\cdot\cos 45\cdot\frac{Gm^2}{L^2}=\left(\frac12+\sqrt2\right)\frac{Gm^2}{L^2}\tag{1}$$

Additionally, from the Newton's law for the angular rotation,

$$F=mr\omega^2=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}mL\omega^2\tag{2}$$

where $r=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}L$ is the radius of the rotation. Combine (1) and (2) to obtain the period of the rotation,

$$T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L^3}{Gm}\left(\frac{4-\sqrt{2}}{7}\right)}$$